# Create a new array with some values of an existing array in JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The array I have is as follows. Let's call this array `reduction`.

```
var reduction = [
    {
        ReductionID: 5813,
        PatiendID: 945994,
        ProviderAcctNumber: "",
        Discharge: "945994 : 01/01/0001 - 01/01/001",
        Selected: 1,
        Balance: 20,
        Charges: 10
    }
];
```

I want a new array (`patientDetails`) with only two values in the format

```
{
   PID: 945994 // which is PatientID in the reduction array
   selection: 1// which is Selected in the reduction array
}
```

What I want in the second array is :

- Only two values from 1st array(reduction)
- The two names should be different in 2nd array(ie., PatientID should ne PID)
- Values are same as the values in 1st array

Is it possible to do with `map()` function ?

Comment: yes, it is possible, although you can do it with a very simple `for` loop. Have you tried?

Comment: I tried using map(). But assing values with adifferent name I didn't get

Comment: Please, show us your attemp. We expect it here in SO, since we don't like to write all code for users, we prefer to see some effort and then guide people in a way to fix issues

Comment: Dont use screenshots. Instead provide code so we can use it more easily to create our answeres. I've edited your question.

Comment: @CalvinNunes : it looks like you over-complicate ;) for some people it is just a low hanging fruit, traditionally (though unfair), OP gets downvoted, while couple of dudes score some rep for good-old `Array.prototype.map()`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it like this

```js
var arr = [{
    ReductionID:5813,
    PatientID: 945994,
    ProviderAcctNumber:"",
    Discharge: "945994 : 01/01/0001 - 01/01/001",
    Selected: 1,
    Balance: 20,
    Charges: 10
}];

var updatedArr = arr.map((obj)=>{
    return {
        PID:obj.PatientID,
        selection:obj.Selected
    }
});

console.log(updatedArr);
```

Here we iterate over the original array using `map` and select the values we need & return the Object as required

Answer (score 5):

`map` here is the best approach for you. 
You can simply do:

```js
var reduction = [
    {
        ReductionID: 5813,
        PatiendID: 945994,
        ProviderAcctNumber: "",
        Discharge: "945994 : 01/01/0001 - 01/01/001",
        Selected: 1,
        Balance: 20,
        Charges: 10
    }
]
 const patientDetails = reduction.map(({PatiendID,Selected}) => ({PID: PatiendID, selection: Selected}))
 
 console.log(patientDetails) //  [{"PID": 945994, "selection": 1}]
```

Here callback function of map iterates over each elements reduction and returns a new object with only `PID` and `selection`

Comment: As long as you used destructuring, you could have gone all the way through: `reduction.map(({PatientID:PID,Selected:selection}) => ({PID,selection}))`